# why Unity Resources.Load perfect working fine in editor, but not in standalone build?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

On my project I need load sprites from resources. In editor this code working perfectly, but in standalone build `Resources.Load()` return null.

`var q = Resources.Load<Sprite>(path);` - using to load sprite, where `path="Assets/Resources/bg/img.jpg"`

Why it's not working in editor?

Comment: Remove the `Assets/Resources` portion of the path.

Comment: @hijinxbassist thanks, i removed `Assets/Resources` and `.jpg`, but  it did not help. Now path has the form `path="bg/img"`

Comment: Did you import your jpg as a sprite?  Double check the import settings. (click on the image, in inspector set `Texture Type` to `Sprite (2D and UI)` and click apply).

Comment: @hijinxbassist Yes, all `.jpg` and `.png` files in Resources folder have texture type `Sprite(2D and UI)`, but no one files not load in standalone build

Comment: Would need to see the actual implementation.  I was able to locally create a folder name `bg` with a sprite named `img` inside, and was able to load in editor and build fine.  There must be some other issue.